# Powershell - what's this line saying?

Tags: windows, powershell

I am a ServiceNow developer. I am dealing with a powershell script which I am not aware of. Can anyone tell me what's going on in the below line? Thanks!

```
$currentuserid = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_computersystem -ComputerName $workstation | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Username
```

Comment: This is getting the current username that is logged into the system by getting the `username` property of the `wim32_computersystem` WMIObect and assigning it to the variable `$currentuserid`

Comment: Google is a pretty solid search engine; you'll find that if you read any Microsoft pages that it turns up when you use [`Get-WMIObject`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-wmiobject?view=powershell-5.1), [`Win32_ComputerSystem`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/cimwin32prov/win32-computersystem), and [`Select-Object`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-6) as search terms, you'll easily have enough information to analyse this statement yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @jrider. Can you also confirm this?  -ComputerName $workstation

Comment: `-ComputerName $workstation` is a variable that is provided to get the information from a remote computer.

Comment: @Backin can you please differenciate b/w -ComputerName $workstation

Comment: @Rakesh I am not 100% sure what you mean. `-ComputerName` is a property that can be defined in the cmdlet `Get-WMIObject` so that you may get information from a remote computer. `$workstation` would represent a `string` value for the name of a computer you wish to get data from. What you provided does not give full context to elaborate any further. `$workstation` is not defined and would only really be used when it needs to be dynamically added, such as in a `for loop`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets break apart this command

```
$currentuserid = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_computersystem -ComputerName $workstation | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Username
```

In powershell **$** is the identifier for a variable. This means **$currentuserid** will equal the output of the last command in the pipe, In this case **Select-Object**.

Also in powershell **-whatever** after a command is a parameter.

The **|** symbol is pipe.

**Get-WmiObject** is a command making a WMI call to the **win32_computersystem** via the **-class** paramater, which is just some basic information about the computer system. **-ComputerName** parameter with the variable **$workstation** means do a remote WMI call to  another computer which is unknown to me becuase i dont know whats inside the variable $workstation. The Output is then piped **|** to a **select-object** command which allows you to cut out data from a property. The parameter -ExpandProperty means to just return what the value of the property equals. The property value he wanted was Username

In simple terms it is getting the username from the Win32_computersystem class in a WMI call to a unknown remote system

Comment: That's a great explanation. Thanks!